# Combining two conditions in must_not ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently writing some search queries for Elastic but with this one I'm stuck:

My index has different documents which all contain the property "dish". The value for "dish" is a list, for example:

```
"dish" : ["Pizza","Pasta","Calzone"]
"dish" : ["Pizza","Calzone"]
"dish" : ["Pasta","Calzone"]
"dish" : ["Pizza","Pasta"]
```

I only would like to exclude the documents where the list contains both "Pizza" AND "Pasta" as dish.
This means that I would like to keep the 2nd and 3rd and have the following results:

```
"dish" : ["Pizza","Calzone"]
"dish" : ["Pasta","Calzone"]
```

I've been trying to write a must_not query based on a related StackOverflow post but I did not succeed in having the correct results:

```
"query": {
"bool": {
    "must_not": [
        {
            "term": {
                "dish": "Pizza"
            }
        },
        {
            "term": {
                "dish": "Pasta"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone help me with this code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by this query (combination of mustNot and must)

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "mustNot": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "dish": "Pizza"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "dish": "Pasta"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned by Ozlevka, if you want to use *term* query give the value in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. Parenthesis is not needed before value. If it is still not working please post the mapping for the field "dish"

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must_not": [
        {
            "term": {
                "dish": "Pizza"
            }
        },
        {
            "term": {
                "dish": "Pasta"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I've changed it in the question!

Answer (score 0):

> Important note: Array into elastic search didn't impact on indexing process. So indexing ["Pizza","Pasta","Calzone"] and sting "Pizza Pasta Calzone" will be the same. Also important to remember that the "term query" is working directly with tokens. Elasticsearch default tokenizer has a lowercase filter. So no capital letters in tokens.

Your query that will works looks as:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "dish": "pizza"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "dish": "pasta"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query will return 0 matches according to the next reasons:

1. You ask to eliminate all documents that contain the word "pizza". Only one document doesn't contain the word pizza: ["Pasta","Calzone"]
2. You ask to eliminate documents contain the word "pasta". So document ["Pasta","Calzone"] also eliminated from matches.

According to how your dataset looks your ask case that impossible to implement by one query.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do you know how I could implement it correctly?

Comment: For the given case, I'm really haven't a clue... Sorry